# SSO Kerberos Apache2 "No key table entry found matching" error

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, kerberos

I am working on a wordpress page that uses NTLM SSO with LDAP Integration.

The problem that I am having is that, for some reasons when you acces the website I am getting a 500 Internal server error and the following error in error.log from apache2.

I am running:

`Linux intranet.website.de 4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u5 (2019-08-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

```
[pid 593:tid 139997705381632] [client 10.15.200.12:33659] gss_acquire_cred() failed: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (, No key table entry found matching HTTPS/intranet.website.de@), referer: https://intranet.website.de/
```

Here is my `krb5.conf` file.

```
    [libdefaults]
    default_realm = DC.WEBSITE.DE

# The following krb5.conf variables are only for MIT Kerberos.
    kdc_timesync = 1
    ccache_type = 4
    forwardable = true
    proxiable = true

# The following encryption type specification will be used by MIT Kerberos
# if uncommented.  In general, the defaults in the MIT Kerberos code are
# correct and overriding these specifications only serves to disable new
# encryption types as they are added, creating interoperability problems.
#
# The only time when you might need to uncomment these lines and change
# the enctypes is if you have local software that will break on ticket
# caches containing ticket encryption types it doesn't know about (such as
# old versions of Sun Java).

#   default_tgs_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1
#   default_tkt_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1
#   permitted_enctypes = des3-hmac-sha1

# The following libdefaults parameters are only for Heimdal Kerberos.
    fcc-mit-ticketflags = true

[realms]
    DC.WEBSITE.DE = { 
        kdc = DC.WEBSITE.DE:88
        admin_server = DC.WEBSITE.DE:749 
    }
[domain_realm]
    website.de = DC.WEBSITE.DE
    dc.website.de = DC.WEBSITE.DE
    .website.de = DC.WEBSITE.DE
    .dc.website.de = DC.WEBSITE.DE
[logging]
        default = FILE:/var/krb5/kdc.log
        kdc = FILE:/var/krb5/kdc.log
```

Lines that I added to `apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/html>

  AuthType Kerberos
  KrbAuthRealms DC.WEBSITE.DE
  KrbServiceName HTTPS
  Krb5Keytab /etc/krb5.keytab
  KrbMethodNegotiate on
  KrbMethodK5Passwd on
  require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Output of `klist -k /etc/krb5.keytab` command:

```
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  14 HTTPS/INTRANET.WEBSITE.DE@DC.WEBSITE.DE
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me out, I googled and tried to fix the issue by myself for the past 4-5 hours but not success.

P.S: This is the command that I use to generate Keytab

```
 ktpass -princ HTTPS/INTRANET.WEBSITE.DE@DC.WEBSITE.DE -pass ****** -mapuser intranetsso@DC.WEBSITE.DE -Ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL -out "C:\Users\adminx\Desktop\krb5.keytab"
```

Comment: The `krb5.keytab` being used in the Apache configuration really is the same one you created with `ktpass`?

Comment: @roaima, yes, it's the same keytab file.
`kinit` command works, it doesn't give a fail output or anything, when I type in the password it doesn't say anything.

Comment: have you found a solution?